# Xindy and indexentries spanning multiple pages

Tags: indexing, xindy

## The Problem

I have the following MWE which does the pageranging wrong:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{Eine Seite|(}\index{Drei Seiten|(}
\blindtext
\index{Eine Seite|)}
\index{Zwei Seiten|(}\index{Zweimalig}
\Blindtext[4]
\index{Zwei Seiten|)}\index{Zweimalig}
\Blindtext[5]
\index{Drei Seiten|)}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `xelatex main && xindy -M texindy -M range-pages -C utf8 -L german-duden main.idx && xelatex main` it creates the following index:

```
Index
D
Drei Seiten, 1–3
E
Eine Seite, 1
Z
Zwei Seiten, 1, 2
Zweimalig, 1, 2
```

This seems odd to me, since it suggests, that I have at least two independent entrys of "Zwei Seiten" on the pages 1 and 2.

Using `makeindex` instead creates an index as I would do it by "hand":

```
Index
Drei Seiten, 1–3
Eine Seite, 1
Zwei Seiten, 1–2
Zweimalig, 1, 2
```

Here we can see clearly, that "Zwei Seiten" has an explanation that begins at page 1 and ends at page 2 whilest "Zweimalig" is mentioned independently at least two times at pages 1 and 2.

How can I make `xindy` behave *exactly* as `makeindex` does with the page-ranges? I still need `xindy`s caption of the lettergroup and unicode capabilities (If there weren't the last requirement I had already switched to `makeindex`).

Exactly the same behaviour means:

- If we have a spanning index (`\index{a|(}\index{a|)}` that spans multiple pages, I want to see a range like "1-2" or "2-5" or whatever.
- If there are onetime mentions (`\index{a}`) on consecutive pages, I want to have them listed separated by commas like "1, 2", "2, 3, 4", but I am fine if large numbers of 5 or more consecutive pages would be consolidated to a range.

**Before answering or commenting**
Please compare the output of `xindy` and `makeindex` especially with "Zweimalig" und "Zwei Seiten", I want the output of `makeindex` but want to use `xindy`!

Comment: As far as I can remember, by default, xindy only forms a range if it spans three or more consecutive pages. This can be changed using the `min-range-length` in a style file.

Comment: Yupp, but than also "Zweimalig" is displayed as "1–2" which I explicitely consider as wrong!

Comment: Your assertion that you want the output of `xindy` to be exactly like `makeindex` contradicts your request for non-range forming. `xindy` and `makeindex` only behave differently in the case of two sequential pages. `makeindex` will convert 1,2,3 to 1--3.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a range-pages module in my xindy, it is called page-ranges.xdy.

Add

```
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers"
               ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
```

to the module or to a copy to change the minimal range (the code is from the ff-ranges.xdy). As far as I know new modules must be either in the main texmf-root or in the current directory as xindy doesn't search other trees with kpathsea.

Comment: OK, range-pages 's pages-range was a typo. But again setting min-range-length does also typeset a range for "Zweimalig" while makeindex does not. So I don't want a range here. Please read the bullet point list where I describe how I want a single index and an index-range to be treated differently!